# All upload destinations not visible in assets when opened from wygwam

Tags: assets, wygwam

I have several different upload destinations in my site, primarily one for images only, named "Images", and one for all kinds of files, named "Documents". I've chosen Assets to be the filemanager to use in Wygwam. Problem is, when I insert a new link in a wygwam field, and choose "Browse server", the only visible upload destination in the Assets popup is "Images".

There doesn't seem to be anywhere to select which upload destinations should be visible, and I'm pretty sure this has worked on other sites in the past. Anyone know what's going on?

I'm using EE 2.7.3, Wygwam 3.2.2 and Assets 2.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Add-Ons > Modules > Wygwam > [your config], and clear out the Upload Directory setting. Then Assets will show all of them.

Comment: Ah thanks! It wasn't set but saving the config fixed it.